# Application Error when I deploy to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my node js app on Heroku but I keep on gettin an application Error when I open the page :
[image]

So I decided to go into logs to see what was happening :
[image]

It says something about module.js 471 ,I don't exactly know where I'm going wrong ,can you please tell if you know .

Comment: It says that it `cannot find ./production.js` file. Check the name of file and path to it in your project.

Comment: I don't have that file in my project ,I never created it ,I don't understand why it's looking for it

Comment: `/app/config/index.js` what is written there on line 39?

Comment: found that line it's this : require('./' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js') || {});

Comment: your environment variable value is production that is why it is loading that file. Try to not provide that variable, or create production.js file.

Comment: where can I find an example of a production.js file ?